# Why isn't every comma character tackled in the code?

Tags: c++

Below is a piece of code I was trying to use to remove the (`,`) from a string. But I find that there's an issue when more than one concerned char is present side-by-side.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string s; cin >>s;
for (int i=0; i<=s.length()-1; i++)
    if (s.at(i)==',')
        {s.erase(s.begin()+i); cout<<s<<endl;}
cout<<s;
return 0;
}
```

Note that I have yielded the resultant string after every operation so that it's easier to understand.

Here's the output when more than one (`,`) are placed in a row:

```
ff,,f,,ffff,,,,ff,f,f.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,,ffff,,,,ff,f,f.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,,,ff,f,f.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,,ff,f,f.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,ff,f,f.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,fff,f.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,ffff.,fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,ffff.fwer..ew,,,
ff,f,ffff,,ffff.fwer..ew,,
ff,f,ffff,,ffff.fwer..ew,
ff,f,ffff,,ffff.fwer..ew,
```

Comment: Why not simply use `s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ','), s.end());`?

Comment: Its because when you delete a comma, it shifts everything after it forward one position in the string, but you still increment 'i' meaning it skips the character that replaces the comma when its deleted

Comment: So is your goal to remove all commas from the string?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Oh okay, I get that. I am not quite familiar with these actually. Thanks @above(s)

Comment: @Mathbg -- Also, don't do this: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  Include the proper header files, not this one, as this has all sorts of implications (not standard is just one of them).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sure, thanks a lot

Comment: @Mathbg: Why are you writing an answer in the comments section?

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must conditionally increment the index. Looking at `ff,,f`

- `s[0]` is `f`
- `s[1]` is `f`
- `s[2]` is `,` -> remove `,`
- now `s` is `ff,f` and `s[3]` is `f`, *but `s[2]` is `,`*

To fix this, you must increase the index only, when the current character is *not* `,`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
    if (s.at(i) == ',') {
        s.erase(s.begin() + i);
        cout << s << endl;
    } else {
        // current character is not ','
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to erase all commas in a string, the easiest way to do that is to use [std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) from the `<algorithm>` header.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string s = "This,,,,string,,contains a,,,,lot,of,,commas,,,";
   s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ','), s.end());
   std::cout << s;
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/29FiWZ)

The code above removes the need to write `for` loops and erase a character at a time.  Your current method of using a `for` loop and erasing a single comma character at a time is not as efficient as the code above.

The `remove` algorithm doesn't actually remove items, but moves them to the end of the container, and thus returns an iterator to the beginning of the items that were "removed".  The `erase` is called upon to do the final removal of the elements at the end of the container.

Comment: I get you and cppreference seems good for quick references of functions

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just iterate through the string backwards, that way you don't need the conditional iterate, as the remaining parts to check wont move.

This can be a good pattern for any "iterate through collection, checking each item and removing if necessary" type thing.

```
for (int i = s.length()-1; i >=0; i-- ) {
    if (s.at(i) == ',') {
        s.erase(s.begin() + i);
        cout << s << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had done that when the one I mentioned in the post failed. Thanks anyway :)